# how to call unmanaged dll from managed c++

Tags: c++, .net, clr, managed

I am calling an unmanaged DLL from managed C++. The DLL has more than one native dependency. I am trying to compile this through Visual Studio.

I have done the following:

1. Added the directory that contains the DLLs and the .lib to Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library directories
2. Added the unmanaged .lib to Properties -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

However, I get linking errors for the functions that I refer to. I haven't added any DLL or lib to the project except for the header file of the library.

UPDATE:
So it is able to find the .lib because if I give a bogus .lib in additional dependencies I get compilation error of the .lib not found. The error that I have is "unresolved token .... " .

Comment: You need to specify the lib file in your project.  Also, DLL's are not used in the build process, so mentioning them in your description is a moot point.  DLL's are used at run time, not at build time.

Comment: If you figure this out, please post the solution, I have been struggling with this lately. I wrote an unmanaged DLL in another compiler and it works just fine in C# using PInvoke, and the header compiles fine in managed C++, but the .lib won't link correctly, the linker is looking for some god-awful-ugly clr-based import names that only VC++ seems to produce if I write the DLL in VC++ only. I have to use a non-VC++ compiler, VC++ is not an option (can't migrate the code), but I need the DLL to work in managed C++ correctly. Using a `.def` file does not help, or I'm not getting the syntax right

Comment: Post the linker error messages!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a good read of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx).  Calling DLLs from C# is straightforward, because .NET supports it and managed C++ is just another .NET implementation, and should also be straightforward.